# translation - how come the word "home" isn't in here

Tags: translation, meaning

So I translated "you can't go home again" into Japanese, from Google translate, and the output looks more akin to "you"ll never return"

Output: もう帰ることはできません

Why doesn't the sentence make any mention of home (in the sense of a place of feeling at home, not essentially a house)?

Is this translation incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

帰る means 'to return to one's home'. 'Return' in a more general sense is 戻る.